# PHP match two arrays and give match a color

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function with two arrays.

One array called `$user` and one array called `winner`
both have 10 numbers in the array.

How can i find out how many numbers in `$user` that matches the `$winner` ?
and for each match, you wrap the spesific number from `$user` with a span color of green.

I have written a code , but it wont match them correctly of course, cause the number may be anywhere in the array, not on the same spot.

current code:

```
 function calculateMatches($user,$winner) {
        sort($user);
        sort($winner);

        $x=0;
        $match = 0;

        foreach($winner as $number) {



            if ($number == $user[$x]) {
                $user[$x] = "<span style=\"color:green;\">".$user[$x]."</span>";
                $match++;
            }

            $x++;}

        return array('match' => $match,'user' => $user, 'winner' => $winner);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_array` with `array_search`.

```
if(in_array($number, $user) {
    $x = array_search($number, $user, true);
    $user[$x] = "<span style=\"color:green;\">".$user[$x]."</span>";
    $match++;
}
```

Comment: but how does it know that $x in this case is the value that matches? ( it could be upto 10 matches)

Comment: current output:
3,6,19,20,23,24,25,31,39,45
|
7,24,26,34,37,38,41,43,44,49

where it says 6 is the match.?

Comment: You want to set the third argument of `array_search` to `true`.

Comment: I have one last question.

im also serializing this, saving to db, and later unserializing it to future use.
now. the matches are stored with the span in the db. like:

|a:10:{i:0;s:35:"<span style="color:green;">5</span>";i:1;s:1:"9";i:2;s:2:"12";i:3;s:2:"26";i:4;s:2:"33";i:5;s:2:"36";i:6;s:2:"37";i:7;s:2:"43";i:8;s:2:"45";i:9;s:2:"48";}|

the question, can you make the code also ignore the style span?, so it would work without removing it? do u get what i mean? :P

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that is best asked in a new question :) @maria

Comment: i see. i have one more small problem with the code. wanna chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112757/discussion-between-maria-and-albzi).

Comment: I can not chat, sorry! Please open up a new question and I will look at it for you! :) @maria

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_intersect . This will give you all the matches.

```
$new_arr = array_intersect($user, $winner);

print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_search()`. [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/kZkXP)

```
$user = array(10,11,15,17,18,21,24,26,41,50);
$winner = array(2,10,15,17,19,21,22,28,35,50);

$match = 0;
foreach($winner as $number){
    $x = array_search($number, $user, true);
    if($x !== false){
        $user[$x] = "<span style=\"color:green;\">".$user[$x]."</span>";
        $match++;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
echo $match;
```

Comment: can you share `$winner` and `$user` array??

Comment: in this example: ( user| winner)

10,11,15,17,18,21,24,26,41,50
|
2,10,15,17,19,21,22,28,35,50

Comment: a var dump : ( winner | user) http://prntscr.com/b7rplo
 and a image of it: http://prntscr.com/b7rpqp

Comment: Did you get what you want??? or need other things... You may deign the output yourself.

Comment: if you look at the last image. ( the one of the left side should have the color etc.. ) and the right side is the winner array, it wont work for me as it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112761/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-maria).